# Get user input from Entry (Tkinter) on click of Button

Tags: python, button, tkinter, function, user-data

Code objective: to get User data on click of Button using Tkinter and 
Code as follows:

```
class myClass:

    def OnClick():
        userData = entry.get()
        root.destroy()
        return userData

    def myFunction()
        <My code which creates GUI>
        button = Button (app, text="Submit", command=OnClick)
        button.grid()
        root.focus_set()
        root.mainloop()
        return userData


Object = myClass()
GetUserData = Object.myFunction()
print GetUserData
```

As user Enters a number on GUI and Clicks on Button, `OnClick()` function should return that value to `myFunction()` then it should return for `GetUserData`, but this code is not working as my objective.

Comment: your indentation is messed up. Can you please fix it? Is `useData` part of `myFunction1`? Is `OnClick` inside `myFunction1`? Also, are you destroying the root window on purpose? Do you intend to recreate it, or is this a temporary GUI you only use briefly while your program runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for this,
Had to declare `userData` as `global`, that made my solution.