# How to get user input from tkinter entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Sorry for the long question. I'm not looking for someone to do it for me, I just need a conceptual overview of how to solve this problem, maybe with a MWE illustrating a fundamental concept.

I want to have a tkinter button that calls a function which requires user input for three things. This user input needs to be gathered from the entry with input questions, similar to `input("Input a number: ")`

Specifically it needs to:
a) delete the entry
b) add a question (to the entry) asking for a number
c) have the user enter that number with other buttons (the first one deleting the entry)
d) save this number
e) repeat this process two more times
f) input those three numbers into the rest of the function

My goal is to have a button that calls a function which asks (In the entry bar) the user for the domain and range and samples of the x and y axes for a plotly graph, then plots said graph.

Here's a MWE illustrating a try I had at making this work, maybe it can show you what I mean.

```
    from tkinter import *
    def function_user_input():
        entry.delete(0,END)
        entry.insert(END,"Please enter your number")
    def function_example_one():
        if entry.get()=="Please enter your number":
            entry.delete(0,END)
            entry.insert(END,1)
    def function_example_two():
        if entry.get()=="Please enter your number":
            entry.delete(0,END)
            entry.insert(END,2)
    window=Tk()
    entry=Entry(window)
    entry.pack()
    button_user_input=Button(window,text="get user input",command=function_user_input)
    button_user_input.pack()
    button_1=Button(window,text="1",command=function_example_one)
    button_1.pack()
    button_2=Button(window,text="2",command=function_example_two)
    button_2.pack()


window.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much.

I tried researching online, but to no avail. In short, I want a function that asks for three separate values in the entry bar of a tkinter GUI, then inputs those numbers into a later part of the function.
I couldn't make sense of [Get user input from Entry (Tkinter) on click of Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365516/get-user-input-from-entry-tkinter-on-click-of-button) as my python skills are still developing.

Comment: Correct me, do you want user input to update either button widget(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to break your problem in smaller steps:

1. When a button is clicked, clear the entry field and ask the user for a number.
2. Store this number in a list or other data structure when another button is clicked, then repeat the process until you have all the numbers you need.
3. Once you have all the numbers, call a function to create the graph.

I solved the problem via a class, since it's more readable and easier to use:

```py
class InputCollector:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.entry = Entry(self.window)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.button_user_input = Button(self.window, text="Get user input", command=self.function_user_input)
        self.button_user_input.pack()
        self.button_submit = Button(self.window, text="Submit number", command=self.function_submit)
        self.button_submit.pack()
        
        self.input_values = []
        self.input_counter = 0

    def function_user_input(self):
        self.entry.delete(0, END)
        self.entry.insert(END, "Please enter your number")

    def function_submit(self):
        if self.entry.get() != "Please enter your number":
            self.input_values.append(float(self.entry.get())) # float to plotting
            self.input_counter += 1
            if self.input_counter < 3: # change this number depending on how many inputs you need
                self.function_user_input()
            else:
                self.plot_graph()

    def plot_graph(self):
        # Here is where you put your function to plot the graph
        print("Plotting graph: ", self.input_values)

    def run(self):
        self.window.mainloop()

app = InputCollector()
app.run()
```